# access a file in python that is created from SunGridEngine

Tags: python, sungridengine

i have a python script, that submits an job to the SGE (Sun Grid Engine).
When the job is done i want to access the output file, generated from the SGE job.
i see with "ls" in the directory that the file is already existing and the job is done, but python needs about 20-30 seconds to get access to that file...

is there a way to detect new created files faster ??

my problem is to differ between "need time to access the file" or "file is not existing"

i tried:
os.path.exist(path)
os.access(path,os.R_OK)

does not solve my problem =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created a sleep timer which checks every second for access..
after some time (~15s), access is granted and file is usable!